# How do I get the value of this void* back?

Tags: c++, pointers, void

I have a void pointer of which I can set the value just fine (at least I think I did it right). But when I try to get the value of what is stored there, all I get nothing back. Doesn't matter if the void* points to a string or int or anything else.
What am I missing here?

```
class Vertex2{
public:
    int _id;

    void *_data;

    template<typename T>
    T getData() {
        T *value = (T*)_data;
        return *value;
    }

    template <typename T>
    void setData(T data) {
        _data  = &data;
    }
};
```

Comment: _date should be type T not cast to void and back. You should work on your design.

Comment: Is `setData` storing the address of a temporary copy?

Comment: @RyanWilson What's this?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit It's a definition of what a void pointer is and how it works.

Comment: "Doesn't matter if the void* points to a string or int or anything else" hum, yes it does matter, because if you dont match the type you get with the type set before you end up in undefined behaviour land

Comment: @RyanWilson: Yes it may well be that, but would you mind explaining the motivation behind your inserting that comment? By the way, a `void` pointer can point to an *array* as well as an *object*, and even another pointer.

Comment: @Bathsheba The OP didn't seem like they completely understood how it worked, so I posted a definition. I don't see why that is a problem.

Comment: `std::any` might get rid of this `void*` and would be a safer.

Comment: @RyanWilson Where did you get it from? Where's the attribution? Why is it formatted like code? How does it address the question?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit It doesn't address the question as it's not an answer now is it? It's more to do with helping clear up the OP's understanding of what a void pointer is and how it works. Here's where it came from (https://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/613-void-pointers/)

Comment: @RyanWilson Even comments should at least be vaguely relevant to the point at hand. And please attribute your sources next time you copy/paste.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Well, if the OP has a problem with it, then they will say so.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try it like this:

```
// the entire class should be templated and you should not cast the data to void
template<typename T>
class Vertex2
{
public:
    int _id;
    // data is no longer void
    T m_data;

    // now returning a const pointer to your data and protect it against manipulation from outside
     getData() const {
        return m_data;
    }

    // was setting the address of a temporary, that will not work. Now it takes a copy and moves that to the member.
    void setData(T data) {
        m_data = std::move(data);
    }
};
```

I have added comments in the code.

As to your code

> ```
> template <typename T>
> void setData(T data) {
>     _data  = &data;
> }
> ```

Do not do that. You store the address to the temporary copy of data. This will go wrong!

> `void *_data;`

Do not store the data as void, template the class like this:

```
template<typename T>
class Vertex2
{
    T m_data;
    .
    .
    .
```

Comment: This is just a non-owning pointer to something that must still be managed elsewhere.

Comment: Your `setData` function takes an unnecessary value copy. `&&` and `std::move` spring to mind.

Comment: @Bathsheba You think this is the first of the OPs worries right now? I can modify it, but I honestly think this is not what is needed atm.

Comment: @Pi: Yes I do. Try to strive for an optimal solution, remembering that Stack Overflow is a Q & A site as opposed to a forum. So therefore don't target an answer specifically at the OP.

Comment: @Bathsheba Alright, I will try to do better in the future. Thanks for the heads up.

Comment: @Pi: Nice. You went for the `std::move` choice? Have an upvote for that!

Comment: @Bathsheba Well, you would have deserved that upvote ;)   BTW it is also what clang-tidy modernize suggested!

Answer (score 6):

`void setData(T data)` receives `data` *by value*.

Setting a pointer to `data` therefore is only valid for the lifetime of that function call.

After that, the pointer *dangles*, and dereference behaviour is *undefined*.

Answer (score 4):

```
template <typename T>
void setData(T data) {
    _data  = &data;
}
```

let's check what's going on here. You store a pointer to a local variable (method argument actually). Right after you leave the method the local var is destroyed and its memory is free to be reused. Now your `void*` points to the same memory address but the memory can contain anything.

Answer (score 2):

There's nothing stored there.

You set the pointer to point to a function argument, that then went out of scope.

You can cast as much as you like, but that object has gone!

This design won't work unless you dynamically allocate.

Consider a `std::variant` or something instead.